# Finding the general form of the plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the general form of the plane in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ that passes through
(1, 1, −3), (−2, 0, 1), and the origin.

How would I start this question?

I know the equation we need to use is: ax + by + cz = d, but not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Evaluate the generic equation at all three points. You'll be able to solve the resulting system of equations for $a,b,c,d$. For example, right away you can see $d=0.$

Comment: plug the points $(1;1;-3), (-2;0;1); (0;0;0)$ in your formula and compute $a;b;c;d$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the comments, the plane equation satisfies the following:

$$\begin{vmatrix} 
x & y & z\\
1 & 1 & -3\\
-2 & 0 & 1 
\end{vmatrix}=0$$

Basically, we want the second and the third row to be coordinates of vectors which define the plane, but we also know that one point is the axes origin.

So we can consider a vector $\vec v = ( 1,1,-3) $ and another one $\vec u= (-2,0,1)$.